# What is a hypernym for holy things or objects in general?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've checked [Word Hyppo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/holy_objects.html), but I cant find a hypernym for 'holy things' that is quite what I want. I feel so sure that there's a word for such things collectively, and I'm looking for a particular one that sounds close to 'acoustics' because that's how I remember it. Any help here, please?

An example: Stealing 'holy things' is sacrilegious.

Comment: From the full OED: [**ritualia**](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/166370) - *Objects used in or connected with rites. Also: ritual activities.*

Comment: Do you mean a collective noun, or a hypernym? 'Cutlery' covers knives, forks etc, but is not a collective noun. You don't speak of a cutlery of ....

Comment: The Catholic term is  _sacramental objects,_ or  just _sacramentals_. They are not sacraments, but they are blessed and/or used in various religious practices. Rosaries, holy cards, palms, candles, incense, holy water, breviaries, etc.

Comment: You still need to clarify. Synonym? Hypernym? Collective noun?

Comment: Absent an example sentence, I am voting to close.

Comment: @JohnLawler, your comment constitutes an answer; why not post it as such?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thanks for that. I have never heard of the word hypernym but I think It's about right.

Comment: You want 'icons, monstrances, candelabra etc are collectively referred to as ____' **not** 'a collection of icons etc is called a treasury'.

Answer (score 1):

**'Relics'**, plural of '[relic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relic)':

> an object esteemed and venerated because of association with a saint or martyr

It's not used exclusively for holy objects, but is I believe strongly associated with it. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relic).

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. ***Relics*** are always the ***preserved physical remains*** (parts of a saint's body or his personal possessions, for example). If a priest for one of the religions that practices baptism were to install a new "baptismal font" in his church, I'm sure that would count as a "holy thing" (and the priest might well bless the new font before using it "in anger"). But a baptismal font would almost never qualify as a "relic". Nor would the "holy" candle some vicars give to the proud parents after a christening ceremony, for example, be called a relic.

Comment: _Relic_ is strictly for pieces of a saint's body, occasionally a strip of clothing, or a piece of whatever killed them.

Comment: @JohnLawler That is a technical definition of 'relic'. As more commonly used it is 'anything old'. Between those two ideas, this works for the OP's situation, 'old religious objects'.

Answer (score 1):

'**Sanctities**':

> [1.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanctity) sacred objects, obligations, or rights
> [2.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sanctity) a sacred thing
> [3.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sanctities) anything regarded as sanctified or holy

From '*sanctity*':

> [1.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanctity) holiness of life and character; the quality or state of being holy or sacred

Not all dictionaries explicate the word as meaning (a) holy object(s), but I think the context and recognizable etymology will dramatically facilitate interpretation.

Comment: But 'lions' isn't a **collective noun** for lions.

Answer (score -1):

*Icons* is a good choice.

If I hear another talking head on television use the word *iconic* to describe a sports star or movie star, I think I'll puke. An icon is a piece of art that elicits reverence from a Christian believer or worshiper. It also inspires prayer, silence, and contemplation.

> [Sacred icons](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/icons) are a form of Christian art especially identified with
> Eastern Orthodoxy, the form of Christianity that emerged in the
> Eastern half of the Mediterranean Basin and then spread into Eastern
> Europe and Russia.

An icon can be two-dimensional, as in a painting, but it can also be three-dimensional, as in the [following](https://fraangelicoinstitute.com/2013/04/16/aidan-harts-new-book-on-sacred-iconography/):

[image]

Comment: Icons are a subclass of the class that the question is about.

Comment: @jsw29: You're right. Don